# Laravel String Validation Failing on "True" and "False"

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Recently it came to my attention that using the following validators in laravel don't work for Boolean like input such as "True" or "False. Although I had a good laugh about it, I am wondering is there any way to have the string validator accept "True" or "False"

```
        'first_name'               => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
        'last_name'                => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
```

If I remove the validation it ends up saving "True" as 1 and "False as "0" in the database.

[image]

Comment: Are you sending data as json?

Comment: Works as a String for other values.

Comment: Please exemplify your request payload, expected behavior and current behavior. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I feel like its a php issue, will run postman tests today, but I dont have much hope

Comment: Can you answer my comment? Exemplify your question, show us: 1. how are you sending data to php (as json payload or form data) 2. How you expect that the data is saved on database 3. how it's being saved. 4. what do you mean by validation don't work? it say that's invalid? it pass thru?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a php issue, you are miss understanding some concepts here.

Comment: Well like in the picture it really looks like a string, so maybe there is a bug in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with postman, this seems like a laravel/php issue.

[image]

Looks like the issue was the legacy middleware that converted boolean-like strings to Booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Well, inputs are stored as strings. If you are using `===`, then you might not ever find a way to make that work. However, you may use `==`. [See the first two rows in the table](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The difference is that `==` tries different types, so it converts the first variable's type to checked in to the second variable's type, while `===` doesn't change the types.